# Building temporary table from S3 file to Redshift

Tags: mysql, postgresql, csv, amazon-redshift

I'm running into consistent errors trying to import a single column of data (all numerical) from S3 into Redshift in the form of a temporary table. Here is my query:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_userid(userid bigint);
COPY tmp_userid (userid) FROM 's3://name/recent_prem_idsonly.txt'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX';
```

which results in:

```
ERROR: Load into table 'tmp_userid' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' 
system table for details.  SQL state: XX000`
```

which then traced shows

```
Error Code 1207: Invalid digit, Value '8', Pos 7, Type: Long
```

I noticed that futzing with the data type for `userid` will drive different errors, so perhaps there's something off there? I've experimented with saving the file as csv and txt.

Comment: Does it work with `CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_userid(userid text);`? Then I would look for invalid data in your file, like the error message suggests.

Comment: It does not- I receive the same error, with a different code which says "String length exceeds DDL length".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the issue was driven by the csv featuring more [empty] columns than Redshift liked. Removing them caused the temp table to be created properly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have by any chance quotes around values in txt/csv file? If yes, remove them, or add 'removequotes' to copy command. (I received same error with quotes in csv file.)

This should work even with temp table, I am doing this all the time (load data to temp table with copy, join them with existing table in Redshift, update/insert to permanent table in Redshift)

Comment: Nope...just integers in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also CREATE a TEMP table with the same schema as the S3 file and then use the COPY command to push the data to that TEMP table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test_table 
(
  userid          VARCHAR(10)
);
    

COPY test_table (userid) FROM 's3://name/recent_prem_idsonly.txt'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX';
```

Answer (score -1):

Temp tables only exist within a single connection. Redshift COPY loads data using an 'out of band' connection that cannot see your temp table. Just use a real table with a "_tmp" suffix and drop it when you're done.

Comment: Unfortunately circling around the same set of errors with this query: CREATE TABLE userid_tmp(userid bigint);
COPY userid_tmp (userid) FROM 's3://name/recent_prem_idsonly.txt'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=XXX;aws_secret_access_key=XXX';

Comment: What's the error now? You may need to GRANT access to the new table to the user that loads the data.

Comment: I don't think this is true. You can use a single connection to run a script with several SQL commands, including creating a temporary table and copying into it, I've done it and it works.

Comment: COPY statement works with temp table, so this comment is probably not 100% correct.